# nextline vba with excel generated emails

Tags: vba, excel, email

After going through the internet I have still ran into an issue with inserting new lines into excel generated emails.

I have tried the following bits of code:

```
 Email = "person@email.com"
 Subj = "Subject"
 body = "Hello Person," & vbCr & _
 "message" & vbCr & _
 "Example: " & vbCr & _
 "another example" & vbCr & _
 "another example" & vbCr & _
 "Thank you. "
```

and

```
 body = "Hello Person," & vbCr & _
 body = body & "message" & vbCr & _
 etc etc
```

and I tried

```
 body = "Hello Person," & vbNewline & _
 body = body & "message" & vbNewline & _
 etc etc
```

the first example works fine but no extra lines. The second example throws a mismatch error

Any idea on what the issue is?

[image]
code to generate email

```
 URL = "mailto:" & Email & "?subject=" & Subj & "&body=" & Msg & "        " & body
 ShellExecute 0&, vbNullString, URL, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus

 Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
 Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
 ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As           String, _
 ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
```

Comment: the mismatch is because the syntax doesn't make sense.  the & _ is basically the IDEs way of creating a line break for the user to get better formatting.  It's syntactically the same as body="Hello Person, " & vbNewLine & body = body & "message".  If you take out the & _ at the end of the first line, it'll work (well it'll get rid of the error).

Comment: It does take the error out but doesnt solve the no extra line issue. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your expected output?  the answer that @Slubee posted addes a line break after each line.  Are you expecting a blank line between "Hello Person," and "message"?  If so, add another vbNewLine, like this: "Hello Person," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _

Comment: Edited original post to include screen shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be very similar to @Slubee 's answer, but I think it's a bit more complete and will hopefully help you pinpoint your issue.  Try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim email As String, _
        subj As String, _
        body As String

    email = "Foo@boo.com"
    subj = "Subject goes here"
    body = "Hello Person," & vbNewLine & _
            "message" & vbNewLine & _
            "Example:" & vbNewLine & _
            "another example" & vbNewLine & _
            "another example" & vbNewLine & _
            "Thank you. "

    MsgBox body

    body = "Hello Person," & vbCr & _
            "message" & vbCr & _
            "Example:" & vbCr & _
            "another example" & vbCr & _
            "another example" & vbCr & _
            "Thank you. "

    MsgBox body
End Sub
```

You'll see that they produce the same thing (and it matches what you put as your screenshot).  My point is, I think the issue is with what you're doing with body variable and not in the way Excel / VBA is constructing the string.

Here is some code to create an email using Outlook that gives the expected result.  If you're not using Outlook, you're going to have to clarify what program you're using to generate the email:

```
Option Explicit

    Sub test()
        Dim email As String, _
            subj As String, _
            body As String

        Dim OutApp As Object, _
            OutMail As Object

        email = "Foo@boo.com"
        subj = "Subject goes here"

        body = "Hello Person," & vbCr & _
                "message" & vbCr & _
                "Example:" & vbCr & _
                "another example" & vbCr & _
                "another example" & vbCr & _
                "Thank you. "

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = email
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = subj
                .body = body
                .Display
            End With
        On Error GoTo 0

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: I think the issue is with how vba is handling the actual body of the email and not the string. I may need to go look into this (or maybe look into outlooks vba stuff)

Comment: @DougCoats can you post your outlook code (or the code you're using to generate the email)?

Comment: @DougCoats Are you using Outlook or Outlook express, or some web-based version?

Comment: out look 2013. I added the private funciton at the top too

Comment: @DougCoats try the code I added in my second block and see it works for you.  It works on my end (also using Outlook 2013)

Comment: Bingo! I guess the way I was doing it was just faulty. Thanks Dude

Answer (score 1):

Use vbNewline to add line.

"hello Person," & Vbnewline &

Comment: try body = "Hello Person," & vbnewline & _ "message" & vbnewline &_ ets etc

Comment: try body = "Hello Person," & vbnewline & "message" & vbnewline & etc

Comment: @DougCoats can you post a mock up of what you're expecting the format of your body variable to be?